# results for windows phone 7 IE compatibility test

Tags: internet-explorer-7, windows-phone-7, cross-browser

what's the result for windows phone 7 IE compatibility test?

Answers should be specific with reference to what works and what doesn't.

Quirksmode says nothing.

EDIT:
The test should consider css 2 & 3, DOM core, DOM HTML, DOM events, CSS Object model view, like in this site: http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

MORE:
in the official blog there is nothing since may [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/iemobile/)

MORE:
the developers vm performs really bad in the acid tests http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/RWVdCcbyRE1CRp5Eqn88YA?feat=directlink 5/100 on acid test 3

Comment: To be of value to the community I think the answer requested should be specific at a feature level. Subjective overall assessments will vary from person to person and achieve little more than create confusion. Could you please edit the question.

Comment: Are you able to offer any context such as what you're trying accomplish?

Comment: oh i thought it was the same question reopened, this is definitely a duplicate then. I'll move my comments there if it's reopened.

Comment: @Mick yeah. On the other hand, it *was* rather unfairly closed, so I can't really blame the OP for opening a dupe. If good answers ensue here, I'm for letting this copy live

Comment: Thanks @Pekka, I think this is an important issue and has a clear reason to be asked.

Comment: I don't mind the question staying open, but as mentioned I would like to see it be done in such a way that's of value to the community per my initial comments. Alfonso, are you able to address this?

Comment: @Mick N. I'll delete the  closed question as soon as it's possible. (in one and a half days)

Comment: Is ok, all has been taken care of. Delete if you want though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser in Windows Phone 7 is currently a stripped down version of the rendering engine from IE7 on the desktop and the javascript engine from IE8.

As you've seen in the ACID tests you linked to the browser scores very low in these.

If you are creating a web page/site that is specifically targetting the browser in WP7, my recommendation would be to keep the layout very simple. Imagine you're targetting an older feeature phone, rather than a smart phone.

It has been strongly hinted that a new browser will be released (OTA) to WP7 phones (hopefully early) in the new year. This newer browser will be based on IE9. Hopefully this will provide many missing features and have much greater handling for CSS.

For reference, PPK also has a mobile compatibility table at http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html. Again this still doesn't include WP7 and I wouldn;t have expected it to until it gains some marketshare.

Comment: ps - I quoted the uninstall reinstall timed trial ref and turns out a different call was made ><

Comment: @Mick sorry, not aware of a public statement on IEMobile v next.

Comment: hehe no worries, will take as is :) certainly makes sense given recent developments. Is the most logical move also. Would be a killer move imo. Will see what happens next.

Answer (score 1):

The WP7 browser is hmm let's say 7.6 IE browser. It is based on 7 but have some stuff from 8. I saw a movie with a review of IE on a device (cannot find the link). The autor said that compatibilty is very good (well it is based on IE 7).

I find WP7 browser pretty fast and didn't see any unusual behavior. (espacially in rendering)